# Where can I get a Windows executable for GNU Bison 3.5.4+?

Tags: parsing, gnu, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

A [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-14150) in bison has been found in releases prior to 3.5.4.

> GNU Bison before 3.5.4 allows attackers to cause a denial of service
> (application crash).

Is there a 3.5.4+ executable available for Windows?

Alternatively, how can [source code](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9735) be used to make the windows executable?

Comment: I really don't get that vulnerability notice. Bison had a bug which caused it to crash on certain bad inputs. GCC also has such bugs. AFAIK, nobody has ever said that those bugs in GCC are DoS vulnerabilities, because you don't let attackers run build tools on your machine. (If they could do that, they would already have exploited a vulnerability.) If a build tool crashes, that's a bug. Nothing more, and nothing to get too worked up about. Just my 2¢.

Comment: As I understand the vulnerability is introduced into the binaries which is compiled using Bison. Is this possible?

Comment: no. It's only a problem when you run Bison. (If it did affect the programs produced by Bison, upgrading Bison wouldn't help much. Your harddrive is full of programs produced with Bison; changing Bison doesn't change anything. You don't need to even have Bison installed to run those programs.)

Comment: I understand what you are telling however I am referring to a production scenario, where the clients are using a product developed by us and our parser is compiled using Bison. So i wanted to build the parser in the next release using the latest version of Bison to mitigate this vulnerability (but it seems like a win exe is not available for newer versions and our build actually takes place on a windows machine).

Comment: Anubhav: the parser you build with boson is safe. (Unless there are bugs in your own code.) Building the parser is also safe, because you are not trying to exploit yourselves. The worst that could happen is that bison could crash instead of building a parser, but that's extremely unlikely, and even if it happens, all that happens is that a 0rogram has crashed on one of your development machines.

Comment: Anyway, if your programmers can't figure out how to build bison from source, you can run bison 9n a linux/unix machine. Exactly the same C (or C++) code will be produced. There is nothing platform dependent in the parser generation.

Answer (score 0):

As of today there are two CVEs about Bison, and both of them are *only* about bison itself (the generator), not about the generated parsers.  So (typical) users should not worry about these CVEs.

I have written to MITRE, and [they agreed to clarify the CVEs](https://lists.gnu.org/r/bison-patches/2020-09/msg00010.html) to avoid confusion.  They now read as follows:

[CVE-2020-14150](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-14150)

> GNU Bison before 3.5.4 allows attackers to cause a denial of service
> (application crash). NOTE: there is a risk only if Bison is used with untrusted
> input, and an observed bug happens to cause unsafe behavior with a specific
> compiler/architecture. The bug reports were intended to show that a crash may
> occur in Bison itself, not that a crash may occur in code that is generated by
> Bison.

[CVE-2020-24240](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-24240)

> GNU Bison before 3.7.1 has a use-after-free in _obstack_free in lib/obstack.c
> (called from gram_lex) when a '\0' byte is encountered. NOTE: there is a risk
> only if Bison is used with untrusted input, and the observed bug happens to
> cause unsafe behavior with a specific compiler/architecture. The bug report was
> intended to show that a crash may occur in Bison itself, not that a crash may
> occur in code that is generated by Bison.

Thanks to @rici for his help on this regard.